# Does performing operations on an empty linked list Node assigned to another node cause change in the original node in python3?

Tags: python-3.x, linked-list, variable-assignment

As mentioned [here](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html), if I have two variables `x` & `y`

```
x = 0
y = x
y += 1
print (x)  #prints 0
```

Here the code will print 0, since assigning `x` to `y` and then changing `y` does not change `x`.
However, in the following code for merging two sorted linked lists([leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-two-sorted-lists/) and [solution](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XIdigk956u0)) and then returning the head of the resultant linked list:

```
class Solution:
    def mergeTwoLists(self, list1: Optional[ListNode], list2: Optional[ListNode]) -> Optional[ListNode]:
        
        dummy = ListNode()
        #assign dummy to tail
        tail = dummy

         
        while list1 and list2:
            if list1.val < list2.val:
                
                tail.next = list1
                list1 = list1.next  # Move list1 pointer forward
            else:
                tail.next = list2
                list2 = list2.next  # Move list2 pointer forward

            tail = tail.next
        
        if list1:
            tail.next = list1
        elif list2:
            tail.next = list2
        #return dummy.next that is head of resultant linkedlist
        return dummy.next
```

even though we do not perform any operations on dummy, and instead add all the nodes to tail, when we finally have to return the head of the resultant linked list, we can do `dummy.next`. I can't understand why?

Answer (score 0):

The difference is between variable (name) assignment and mutation (assignment to attributes):

`y += 1` is a variable assignment and does not perform (object) mutation.

`tail.next = list1` is an attribute assignment and mutates whatever `tail` references.

In the linked list algorithm, `tail` and `dummy` are two memory locations that both start out with a reference to a new node. They reference the *same* node (with a dummy value). Let's assume a simple input of two lists with each a single node:

```
                           ┌───────────┐
                list1:─────┤ val: 1    │
                           │ next: None│
                           └───────────┘

           ┌───────────┐
dummy:─────┤ val: 0    │
tail:──────┤ next: None│ 
           └───────────┘

                           ┌───────────┐
                list2:─────┤ val: 2    │
                           │ next: None│
                           └───────────┘
```

Now the first iteration has the clue. It executes `tail.next = list1`, which **mutates** the object that `tail` references. It is not an assignment to `tail`, so `tail` keeps the same reference (value), but it is the referenced object that gets updated, and so it is expected that you would see this change if you look at that object via `dummy`:

```
                           ┌───────────┐
                list1:─────┤ val: 1    │
                    ┌──────┤ next: None│
                    │      └───────────┘
                    │
           ┌────────│──┐
dummy:─────┤ val: 0 │  │
tail:──────┤ next: ─┘  │ 
           └───────────┘

                           ┌───────────┐
                list2:─────┤ val: 2    │
                           │ next: None│
                           └───────────┘
```

At this point your question is already answered, but let me continue. Next `list1` and `tail` are **assigned** new references, so they refer to something else now:

```
                           ┌───────────┐
                 tail:─────┤ val: 1    │     list1: None
                    ┌──────┤ next: None│
                    │      └───────────┘
                    │
           ┌────────│──┐
dummy:─────┤ val: 0 │  │
           │ next: ─┘  │ 
           └───────────┘

                           ┌───────────┐
                list2:─────┤ val: 2    │
                           │ next: None│
                           └───────────┘
```

`tail` and `dummy` no longer reference the same object once the first iteration has been executed, so another mutation of `tail` will not mutate the object that `dummy` references anymore. But since it is a linked list, the change will be further "down the road" if you start a traversal at `dummy`.

In this example, the loop already exits after the first iteration. This time `tail.next = list2` is executed, and this finishes the merged list:

```
                           ┌───────────┐
                 tail:─────┤ val: 1    │     list1: None
                    ┌──────┤ next: ─┐  │
                    │      └────────│──┘
                    │               │
           ┌────────│──┐            │
dummy:─────┤ val: 0 │  │            │
           │ next: ─┘  │            │
           └───────────┘            │
                        ┌───────────┘
                        │  ┌───────────┐
                        └──┤ val: 2    │
                list2:─────┤ next: None│
                           └───────────┘
```

And now it is clear that `dummy.next` references the node that was assigned to `tail.next` in the very first iteration of the loop.